# Keeping a <li> that was unfolded to stay unfolded after reloading?

Tags: javascript, html

[Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936017/what-is-the-ultimate-toggle-of-this-fold-unfold-state/58936668#58936668)

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09o85xpv/7/) and [bigger preview](https://jsfiddle.net/09o85xpv/7/show). There are collapsable lists and when you click the inner lists of a collapsable list, it will make a request to the backside, and a new template with new data will be rendered.

What I want to do is, if the visitor selected one of the inner lists of a collapsable list, let that collapsable list stay unfolded when a new page is loaded.

I've edited original template without solid understanding of javascript let alone jQuery and have trouble figuring out what to fiddle with.

#### target html

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="inside">
            <h3>{{yourBlogName}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#sometext" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">example list</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="sometext">
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#sometext2" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">example list2</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="sometext2">
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#sometext3" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">example list3</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="sometext3">
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The part that I think is triggering collapse

```
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

What I tried : I use Flask and tried storing the state data every time a new page request occurs. I thought maybe the attribute `aria-expanded="false"` was responsible for the folding and unfolding so applied my flask data to that attribute using jinja template. It didn't work as that attribute was not the trigger of the folding in the first place. Maybe I need a way to store the data in javascript?

Comment: you need to store the state, one possible way is to use localstore and reset the state  based on the stored value on page load

Comment: *"when a new page was loaded"* - Specifically, do you mean the user is reloading this page?  Navigating to a new page?  Something else?  Essentially the high-level approach if you want to persist information across pages would be to persist that information somewhere, possibly in local storage for example, and in the target page you'd check for that information and update the page accordingly.

Comment: @David I mean a new request. It will have a different url, and new data will be gathered from backside and rendered into a new page. By storing, I can imagine 1. click to unfold is triggered 2. the code above makes javascript array saving the current state 3. The array is not destroyed but stays so when a new page is loaded, so I can toggle unfold with another js code when page is rendered. What I have no experience is in number 3. Does javascript code inside html stay when a new page is loaded?

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers: No, code doesn't "stay" when a new page is loaded.  From JavaScript's perspective, loading a page is essentially like opening an application.  Any information that needs to persist between page loads needs to be persisted outside the page.  Take a look at "local storage" in JavaScript.  It allows you to read and write data stored in the browser.  So one page can write a value, and another page can read that value.

Comment: @David Ahh, that clear things up then. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers Also if you're using flask in the back end it may be worth to use session data instead and just pass down that info in the form of the attributes. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm