# What is the ultimate toggle of this fold/unfold state?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've posted a question with the same code but this is a different question. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09o85xpv/7/) and bigger [preview](https://jsfiddle.net/09o85xpv/7/show).

So this `#li.active` inside `#sidebar` is foldable. When the list is toggled to be unfolded by click, we can see the inner lists show up with smooth animation.

```
<nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <div class="inside">
            <h3>{{yourBlogName}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#sometext" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">example list</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="sometext">
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
              <li><a class="innerCategoryList" href="/someLongText}">example inner list</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I originally thought it was an attribute like `aria-expanded` that enabled this folding but it became clear later on that the folding will be enabled as long as I include these references.

```
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

There was actually a JQuery code right next to these references that looked like it was causing the the folding function, but turned out it can be completely removed and still the list will stay foldable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

**So what I'm trying to know is, what should I change, to have a specific list folded/unfolded manually**. Usually we can see the change of view immediately when we edit our dom or css in the inspect. With this, I have not found a way to toggle fold/unfold with my inspect. And I can expect now it is likely to be the jQuery and Bootstrap that are triggering the action. Does this mean that I need to edit the long code of the references to change the folding status of a list manually?

The reason I'm asking this is the inconvenience. Like if I clicked a foldable list `fruit` and inner lists `banana, apple, kiwi` were shown and I clicked `banana`, the `fruit` is shut when the next page was newly loaded. Describing the issue in case there is a get-around to this.

Comment: Look at the documentation for bootstrap which you are using https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link and collapsible content are connected with the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute.

You can show/hide/toggle collapsible elements programmatically using the following code:
`$('#sometext').collapse('hide')`

Here is a [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/) in the bootstrap documentation.

But if you want to keep the state of your list when the page is reloaded it's a completely different topic. There are a lot of things unclear in what are you trying to accomplish, so it would be much more efficient if you could breakdown your problem into smaller ones and solve them one after another. One of the questions you might ask yourself is "How do I know which menu should be expanded in every situation". Can I get this information from the URL? How do I map my URL to a specific state, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Just adding this answer as the problem was solved. As @soeik mentioned, it was a bootstrap that I needed to edit. I stored the the last opened collapsible list to url.

```
<a class="innerCategoryList" 
   href="/useful_function?isInCategory=true&
                         category=python&
                         lastOpenedCategory=python">useful function</a>
```

The back (in this case, python and flask) mirrored it,

```
return render_template(
    "index.html",
    lastOpenedCategory=request.args.get("lastOpenedCategory"),
    ...)
```

And jQuery called the show action. ({{ }} is jinja template grammar)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    if ({{lastOpenedCategory}}!=null){
        var lastOpenedCategory = '#'+{{lastOpenedCategory}}.id
        $(lastOpenedCategory).collapse('show');
    };
});
```